# Shopping cart in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shopping-cart

Are there any tutorials for creating shopping cart functionality in WordPress from scratch? I don't want to use a plugin. I need something that creates it from scratch and it should be:

1. Storing the data (list of products) in cookies
2. At checkout, I want to insert the order into a database and email the admin and customer who placed the order.

Comment: Good advice from @John Robinson.  If you need to ask, it doesn't bode well. Download a free e-commerce plugin and have a look at the code base, there's a lot to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to start a project as large as a shopping cart for Wordpress and need a tutorial, you're in for a long, long road.

There will not be a tutorial for such a thing because anyone up to taking on the task of building a shopping cart from scratch will know how to do it, no offense.

Why not try some solutions like Shopplugin: https://shopplugin.net/

Or jigoshop: http://www.jigoshop.com/